# wicket 9.4 multitab behavior

Tags: wicket

I have a link

```
protected void onInitialize() {
    super.onInitialize();
    Link<Void> myLink = new Link<>("myLink") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            setResponsePage(new MyPage((IModel<MyDto>) getDefaultModel()));
        }
    };
    myLink.setPopupSettings(new PopupSettings());
    myLink.getPopupSettings().setHeight(100).setHeight(100);
    Button button = new Button("button");
    myLink.add(button);
    add(myLink);
}
```

which returns `MyPage` in a pop-up and it works till I open a second tab, refresh the first tab and then instead opening `MyPage` it opens a `home page` in a pop-up window or sometimes complains that
the component was already removed from the page.

So, my questions are

```
Does Wicket 9.4 supports multi tab sessions?

If so, how to enable this functionality?

If no, what would be the workaround?
```

**Update no.1**

What is a hard link?

Comment: Check your server logs for serialization related errors. With `setResponsePage(new MyPage((IModel<MyDto>) getDefaultModel()));` you probably make a hard reference from the current page to MyPage.

Comment: Your description of the steps is not clear. Please try to make it more explicit what exactly you do to see the problem.